# Updating megaraid firmware - errors?

Tags: firmware, flashing, megaraid

I'm trying to update the firmware on an LSI 926x series card from current version (2009) to latest (v12.15?). I've tried the standard commands using "storcli" and "storcli64" in Windows cmd prompt (admin) and get "image corrupted". I have downloaded other archive images from the support pages, it reports them all corrupted as well.

I've also tried booting into recovery in case it needs a cleaner environment and then I get "subsystem needed to support the image type is not present".

What am I doing wrong? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on a supplier website. They said to use MegaCLI from within Windows if I wanted, and upgrade to an intermediate version (12.12 not 12.15 which is the current version), and then upgrade again from that to the current version. It worked. (I don't know if using MegaCLI rather than the usual StorCLI made any difference).

URL:

http://support.bull.com/ols/product/platforms/bullion/bullionExtendedMemory/dl/no-frmf/g/adapt_fw/LSI-12.14.0-0167

Comment: In my case, upgrading only worked through StorCLI; MegaCLI kept failing with the error you posted. Leaving this here in case someone else has the same problem!